# ansible - block conditionnal is ignored

Tags: ansible, block

i have a problem xith a block in an ansible role

**Extract of roles/apps_nifi/tasks/main.yml :**

```
- debug:
    msg: "nifi_extra_instances_name is defined"
  when: nifi_extra_instances_name  is defined

- debug:
    msg: "nifi_extra_instances_name is not defined"
  when: nifi_extra_instances_name  is not defined

- name: Import variables for extra instances of Nifi
  block:
    - set_fact:
        nifi_extra_instances_vars: "{{ item.value }}"
      when: nifi_extra_instances_name in item.key
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', nifi_extra_instances, wantlist=True) }}"

    - set_fact:
        "{{ item.key }}": "{{ item.value }}"
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', nifi_extra_instances_vars , wantlist=True) }}"
      when: nifi_extra_instances_vars is defined and nifi_extra_instances_vars|length > 0
  when: nifi_extra_instances_name is defined
```

nifi_extra_instances_name is a variable setup when i call the role if it is needed.

**plabook main.yml :**

```
- hosts: nifi_hosts
  become: yes

  roles:
    - { role: apps_nifi, tags: nifi }
    - { role: apps_nifi-registry, tags: apps_nifi-registry }
    - { role: apps_nifi-api, tags: apps_nifi-api, become: no }
    #- { role: apps_nifi, tags: "nifi-burn", vars: { nifi_extra_instances_name: burn} }
```

So the variable nifi_extra_instances_name is not defined in this example, i expect that the code into "block" is not played :

```
TASK [apps_nifi : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 14 October 2020  10:39:45 +0200 (0:00:12.496)       0:00:20.193 *****
skipping: [XXXXX]

TASK [apps_nifi : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 14 October 2020  10:39:45 +0200 (0:00:00.052)       0:00:20.245 *****
ok: [XXXXX] => {
    "msg": "nifi_extra_instances_name is not defined"
}

TASK [apps_nifi : set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 14 October 2020  10:39:45 +0200 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:20.300 *****
skipping: [XXXX] => (item={u'key': u'burn', u'value': {u'nifi_dir': u'/local/nifi-burn', u'nifi_web_https_port': 9445, u'nifi_ports': [u'9445:9445', u'9094:9094'], u'container_name': u'bdmpusher-burn'}})

TASK [apps_nifi : set_fact] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
Wednesday 14 October 2020  10:39:45 +0200 (0:00:00.058)       0:00:20.359 *****
fatal: [XXXXX]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: with_dict expects a dict"}
```

any ideas please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `when` condition for a block (as well as for e.g. a `role` stanza at play level, an `import_task`...) is "pushed" up to every affected task. In other words, the condition for the full block is evaluated at every task level.

So the following piece of code:

```yaml
- block:
    - name: do a
      debug:
        msg: a
      when: task_a_condition
    - name: do b
      debug:
        msg: b
      when: task_b_condition
  when: block_condition
```

Is the exact equivalent of:

```yaml
- name: do a
  debug:
    msg: a
  when: task_a_condition and block_condition
- name: do b
  debug:
    msg: b
  when: task_b_condition and block condition
```

Hence, all when conditions are analyzed in whatever case.

Moreover, when looping, the `loop` expression is analyzed first to determine the needed iterations, then the `when` condition is analyzed for every item. In your case, it leads to an error because `nifi_extra_instances_vars` is undefined (and hence not a dict).

You can fix that on that specific task with the following loop expression leading to an empty loop when needed:

```yaml
loop: "{{ query('dict', nifi_extra_instances | default({})) }}"
```

(note: using `query` instead of `lookup` automatically returns a list)

Now, if you really do not want those tasks to play at all even when skipped, there is IMO a better solution:

- Move the block tasks to a separate file and remove the `block` stanza.
- Use `include_tasks` with the same `when` condition as your current block. In this case it will only apply to the include statement itself, not to the individual tasks. **Do not confuse with `import_task`** which would lead to the exact same result as the block for the current problem.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, it's very helpfull
Nice tips withe query :)